# Hide the default parts of a DT:: Datatable

Tags: r, dt

Is there a way to hide specific parts of a DT:: Datatable? I mean `"Show Entries", "Search","Showing to of entries", "Previous" "Next"`. I guess that the way of hiding one of those can be applied to the rest of them.

```
library(DT) 
datatable(
  mtcars, 
  options = 
    list(language = 
           list(paginate = 
                  list('next'="NEXT PAGE", 
                       previous="PREVIOUS PAGE"), 
                info = "These are entries _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ total entries",
                lengthMenu = "Display _MENU_ entries",
                search = "Search box"
           )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following options to enable/disable features of `DataTables`:

- `info` : table information display field
- `paging` : table pagination
- `searching` : search (filtering) abilities

```
library(DT)

datatable(
  mtcars, 
  options = list(
    info = FALSE,
    paging = FALSE,
    searching = FALSE
  )
)
```

See http://datatables.net/reference/option/ for more options.

Comment: Very helpful indeed. Im trying to set lengthMenu to Fbut it does not work